# Нужна помощь, с установкой gulp-sass!

Tags: css, gulp-sass

> на самом деле всё установлено, но когда я пишу некоторые стили в main.sass компилируется в main.css но не отображается на деле (на странице проекта). По всей видимости что то я не правильно подключил

пути указаны вроде верно.(возможно всё таки что то не корректно)

```
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
    concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify        = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
    cssnano       = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
    del           = require('del'),
    imagemin      = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant      = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    cache         = require('gulp-cache'),
    autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/sass/**/*.sass', 'app/sass/**/*.scss']) // Берём 
    источник
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError)) // 
    Преобразуем sass в css
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { 
    cascade: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) //Выгружаем результат в папку css
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) });

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'app/libs/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
        ])
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js')) });

gulp.task('css-libs', ['sass'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app/css/libs.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) });

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
    },
    notify: false
    }); });

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del.sync('dist') });

gulp.task('clear', function() {
    return cache.clearAll(''); });

gulp.task('img', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        interlaced: true,
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlagins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        une: [pngquant()]
        })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); });

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'],
function() {
    gulp.watch(['app/sass/**/*.sass', 'app/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload); });

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: Если есть файл `css` может у вас ошибка в его подключении?

Comment: Проверьте подключение в index. Уберите это из коментария, лучше добавьте в вопрос. Так же проверьте, что пишет консоль браузера, есть ли ошибки.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду в index.html, не правильно подключил css?
можно ли как то в комментарии добавить скрин html  кода?

Comment: Залейте скрин на фотобанк и оставьте ссылку.

Comment: пишет такую ошибку,   Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/app/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.